# Best Practice message: All duties should be part of a process cycle

Tags: axapta, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

I develop in many environments in MS Dynamics AX 2012.

1. I made a Privilege and added some MenuItems under its EntryPoints-section.
2. Then I created a new Duty and added the Privilege under the Privileges-section of the Duty.
3. And finally I added the Duty to a Role.

After exporting the files and importing them to another environment, AX gives me this Best Practice-message: "All duties should be part of a process cycle.".

I'm asking this just to know what this is?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with Ax2012 security architecture. In short, process cycles are structures that contain duties for easier maintenance.
To quote [this Ax2012 role-based security resource](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731787.aspx):

> To help the administrator locate the duties that must be assigned to roles, duties are organized by the business processes that they are part of. In the context of the security model, business processes are referred to as process cycles. For example, in the accounting process cycle, you may find the Maintain ledgers and Maintain bank transactions duties.

Use these [instructions to setup a process cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556870.aspx) and get rid of that BP message.